# How to use nameof for long property-paths to get the "fullnameof"?

Tags: c#

I have following statement:

```
queryPublications += $" AND CC_Publication__r.CC_External_ID__c IN ({inPublicationExtIds})";
```

Now i want to use the [nameof expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/nameof) to get compile time safety for the names, in case something will change in future. But the modified code doesn't look nice anymore:

```
queryPublications += $" AND {nameof(CC_Publication_Subscription__c.CC_Publication__r)}.{nameof(CC_Publication_Subscription__c.CC_Publication__r.CC_External_ID__c)} IN ({inPublicationExtIds})";
```

Consider that there are more fields or the property-path(what's the correct term?) is even longer:

```
AND Class1.Prperty1.Class2.Property2.Class3.Property3 IN
```

The code becomes really ugly and you can easily make mistakes. You have to repeat the whole part that comes before the current.

Is there any way(extension or technique) to simplify my approach?

Would be great if there was a `fullnameof` to get the full path.

Comment: I hate to say, you will not like the answers. This *** is long - a syntax to give a path of nameof would be SOOOOO nice and is definitely missing. Acutally something with Lambdas SHOULD be possble - after all, .Include in Ef(core) is used to extract property names, ALSO through a path. Something similar should be possible.

Comment: @TomTom: really missing a `fulllnameof` but don't know if it's posible at all(seems so if it works in `Ìnclude`).

Comment: There is an open [proposal](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/701) for `fullnameof` in C# lang repo

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski thanks, that is exactly what I need. Now they just have to implement it :)

Comment: Folllow the proporsal link. There is a reference to something in there using lambdas.

Answer (score 6):

You can use expression trees to get the name of the members of an expression:

```
public static string NameOf<T>(Expression<Func<T>> pathExpr)
{
    var members = new Stack<string>();
    for (var memberExpr = pathExpr.Body as MemberExpression; memberExpr != null; memberExpr = memberExpr.Expression as MemberExpression)
    {
        members.Push(memberExpr.Member.Name);
    }
    return string.Join(".", members);
}
```

If you call it like so:

`NameOf(() => CC_Publication_Subscription__c.CC_Publication__r.CC_External_ID__c)`

it will return `"CC_Publication_Subscription__c.CC_Publication__r.CC_External_ID__c"`.

Comment: I'm going to use this to generate config keys by using `string.Join("__"...` so that I can have config sections with the same name as the config class into which they'll be deserialized. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, not sure that will work well for my needs. The `pathExpr` can't just be `() => Class1.Property1`, it would have to be something like `() => someClass1.Property1` where `someClass1` was a pre-existing instance.

Comment: @JoshGallagher You could change `members.Push(memberExpr.Member.Name);` to `if (memberExpr.Expression is ConstantExpression) { members.Push(memberExpr.Type.Name); } else { members.Push(memberExpr.Member.Name); }` so that for the outer (captured) object, i.e. someClass1 the name of its type gets emitted instead.

Comment: Yep, that could work. I was thinking to try something that took `Expression<Func<TClass,TProperty>>` as in my situation I don't have an instance to capture. `TProperty` would be the type of the property at the end of the chain and `TClass` the top level.

Answer (score 1):

This is a build on [@ckuri's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62311137/413075). That answer requires that the first part of the expression be a class instance, a variable. If you don't have an instance of the class (classic `nameof()` doesn't require an instance) then this version could work.

Usage example:

```
var x = NameOf<MainType>(m=>m.MidProperty.FinalProperty);
```

I'll admit, it's not the prettiest. Here's the function definition. Again, heavily borrowed from @ckuri:

```
private static string NameOf<TRoot>(Expression<Func<TRoot, object>> pathExpression)
{
  var members = new Stack<string>();
  for (
    var memberExpression = pathExpression.Body as MemberExpression;
    memberExpression != null;
    memberExpression = memberExpression.Expression as MemberExpression
  )
  {
    members.Push(memberExpression.Member.Name);
  }
  members.Push(typeof(TRoot).Name);
  return string.Join(".", members);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

.NET 6 added [CallerArgumentExpression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callerargumentexpressionattribute?view=net-7.0) which lets you create a workaround version of `fullnameof`.

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

var fullString = StringOf(nameof(HttpResponseMessage.Content.Headers));

// Prints: HttpResponseMessage.Content.Headers
Console.WriteLine(fullString);

static string StringOf(string value, [CallerArgumentExpression(nameof(value))] string fullpath = default!)
{
    // value is: "value"
    // fullpath is: "nameof(HttpResponseMessage.Content.Headers)"
    // Do some validation here...

    string outputString = fullpath.Substring(fullpath.IndexOf("(") + 1, fullpath.IndexOf(")") - fullpath.IndexOf("(") - 1);

    return outputString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's always `string.Format` - you don't always need to use an interpolated string:

```
queryPublications += string.Format(" AND {0}.{1} IN ({2})", 
                     nameof(CC_Publication_Subscription__c.CC_Publication__r),
                     nameof(CC_Publication_Subscription__c.CC_Publication__r.CC_External_ID__c),
                     inPublicationExtIds);
```

Comment: It's a little bit better maybe. But you are still repeating yourself(consider: {0}.{1}.{2}.{3}) and you lose a lot of readability compared to the non-nameof approach especially if you have a lot of fields(a long query).

Comment: Oh yeah, I agree.  At least it's not a 300 character long line.  You could play `const string` games.  Something like `const string a = nameof(A); const string b = nameof(B); const string ab = A +"."+B;` (yeah, still really ugly, but...).  The `nameof` construct results in a `const string` (as does, of course, the concatenation of const strings)