# Improve nameof() in C#

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using ASP.NET Core MVC with C#.

I define my model like this:

```
public class Student
{
      public class FirstName {get;set;}
      public int? PriorityId { get; set; }
}

public class Priority
{
    [Key]
    public int PriorityId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Priority Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }        
}
```

So it will render HTML for priority dropdown like this.

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
     <div class="form-group">
         <label for="Student_PriorityId">Priority<span style="color:red"> *</span></label>
         <select class="form-control valid" id="Student_PriorityId" name="Student.PriorityId" aria-invalid="false">
              <option selected="selected" value="0">Select</option>
              <option value="3">High</option>
              <option value="1">Low</option>
              <option value="2">Medium</option>
         </select>
         <span class="text-danger field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="Student.PriorityId" data-valmsg-replace="true">Priority is required.</span>
     </div>
</div>
```

**Problem**

When I am going to check custom validation the message is not display below dropdown.

```
if (obj.Student.PriorityId <= 0)
{
    ModelState.AddModelError(nameof(obj.Student.PriorityId), "Priority is required.");
}
```

The above code is not working when I try using `nameof()`.

But when I remove `nameof()` and write down as string like below. It shows me error message below drop down successfully.

[image]

```
if (obj.Student.PriorityId <= 0)
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("Student.PriorityId", "Priority is required.");
}
```

Is there any way where I can improve `nameof()` function of C#?

Comment: No, you cannot improve the `nameof()` function.

Comment: `nameof()` will return the name of the variable you put in, and that name is `"PriorityId"`. What benefit does `nameof()` provide here anyways? If you already know what variable you have to put in as parameter, you also know the result ...

Comment: Could you please elaborate what exactly your "did not work" means? Are you getting any compile or runtime error? Or the observed behaviour is not as the expected one? And which one is expected?

Comment: If you want to achieve `"Student.PriorityId"` using `nameof( )`, you could extend the first `AddModelError( )` input value to: `$"{nameof(obj.Student)}.{nameof(obj.Student.PriorityId)}"`.

Comment: @derpirscher `nameof()` is not used because one doesn't know the result (it is always a constant), but because it ensures the value stays correct in case of refactorings.

Comment: IMHO Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62308727/how-to-use-nameof-for-long-property-paths-to-get-the-fullnameof

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is an improvement but you could write a method like this:

```
public static string NameOf<T>(Expression<Func<T>> func)
{
    return string.Join(".", func.ToString().Split('.').Reverse().Take(3).Reverse().ToArray());
}
```

Then your code would be

```
if (obj.Student.PriorityId <= 0)
{
    ModelState.AddModelError(NameOf( () => obj.Student.PriorityId ), "Priority is required.");
}
```

In this case, `NameOf` would return "obj.Student.PriorityId".

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to use [`CallerArgumentExpressionAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callerargumentexpressionattribute?view=net-6.0) as a replacement for `nameof`.

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
public static class ModelStateExtensions
{
    public static void AddModelErrorEx(
        this ModelStateDictionary modelStateDictionary,
        object _,
        string errorMessage,
        [CallerArgumentExpression("_")] string expr = "")
        => modelStateDictionary.AddModelError(expr, errorMessage);
}
```

Usage:

```cs
// Argument 'expr' will be "Student.PriorityId" here.
ModelState.AddModelErrorEx(Student.PriorityId, "Priority is required.")

// Argument 'expr' will be "obj.Student.PriorityId" here.
ModelState.AddModelErrorEx(obj.Student.PriorityId, "Priority is required.")
```